# Stage3D function

Tags: actionscript-3, pixel-shader, stage3d, agal

I've been learning about stage3D, and am trying to render something for the first time. No run-time errors appear during the course of this program, but I am not seeing any output... my code is as follows (with comments where necessary)

```
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.display.*;
import flash.display3D.*;
import flash.display3D.textures.Texture;
import stillicidium.rendering.MeshMaker;
import stillicidium.rendering.AGALMiniAssembler;

stage.scaleMode = 'noBorder';

var context0:Context3D;
var vBuff:VertexBuffer3D;
var iBuff:IndexBuffer3D;
var tex:Texture;

//MeshMaker is designed to make a stage-fitted n-by-n mesh with
//corresponding uv coords - form is like: (x, y, 0 ,u, v)
var mm:MeshMaker = new MeshMaker(this.stage, 20);
var vBuff_vec:Vector.<Number> = mm.GetVertexBuffer();
var iBuff_vec:Vector.<uint> = mm.GetIndexBuffer();
mm = null;

var vShader:AGALMiniAssembler = new AGALMiniAssembler();
var pShader:AGALMiniAssembler = new AGALMiniAssembler();
var program:Program3D;

//Create a shape for drawing
var square:Shape = new Shape();
square.graphics.lineStyle(3,0xffffff,1,true);
square.graphics.beginFill(0xaa00ff,1);
square.graphics.moveTo(100,100);
square.graphics.lineTo(stage.stageWidth-100,100);
square.graphics.lineTo(stage.stageWidth-100,stage.stageHeight-100);
square.graphics.lineTo(100,stage.stageHeight-100);
square.graphics.lineTo(100,100);

//Draw shape as BitmapData to use as texture
var bmpdata:BitmapData = new BitmapData(stage.stageWidth,stage.stageHeight,true,0);
bmpdata.draw(square);

//Initialize stage3D
stage.stage3Ds[0].addEventListener(Event.CONTEXT3D_CREATE, initStage3D);
stage.stage3Ds[0].requestContext3D();

function initStage3D(e:Event):void {
    context0 = stage.stage3Ds[0].context3D;
    context0.configureBackBuffer(stage.stageWidth, stage.stageHeight, 4, true);

    vBuff = context0.createVertexBuffer(0.2 * vBuff_vec.length, 5);
    vBuff.uploadFromVector(vBuff_vec, 0, 0.2 * vBuff_vec.length);
    vBuff_vec = null;

    iBuff = context0.createIndexBuffer(iBuff_vec.length);
    iBuff.uploadFromVector(iBuff_vec, 0, iBuff_vec.length);
    iBuff_vec = null;

    tex = context0.createTexture(bmpdata.width,bmpdata.height,'bgra',false);
    tex.uploadFromBitmapData(bmpdata,0);

    //Passes vertex buffer 1 to fragment shader
    //Outputs vertex buffer 0
    vShader.assemble('vertex', 'mov v0 va1 \n'+'mov op va0');
    //Textures using data from vertex shader and sends to temporary register
    //Outputs temporary register
    pShader.assemble('fragment', 'tex ft0 v0 fs0 <2d,linear,nomip> \n'+'mov oc ft0');

    program = context0.createProgram();
    program.upload(vShader.agalcode, pShader.agalcode);

    addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, render);
}

function render(e:Event):void {
    if (!context0) { return; }
    context0.clear();

    //(x,y,0) to vertex buffer 0, (u,v) to vertex buffer 1
    context0.setVertexBufferAt(0, vBuff, 0, 'float3');
    context0.setVertexBufferAt(1, vBuff, 3, 'float2');
    context0.setTextureAt(0, tex);
    context0.setProgram(program);

    context0.drawTriangles(iBuff);
    context0.present();
}
```

I've compared this to several online examples, and have found no discrepancies. I'm thinking that there might be some setting I'm overlooking, or requirement I'm missing... I'm lost though. Thoughts?

Comment: Perhaps it's something with the mesh I'm passing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mesh size wasn't correct - the tutorials I read failed to mention that x, y, and z values used as vertex shader output are between -1 and 1. Hazarding a guess: my mesh fell outside the zone being rendered, and all the polygons were lost during the stage of rendering where the viewport is clipped.